# Ubuntu 14.04 has screen ghosting

Tags: screen

lubuntu and ubuntuMATE 14.04; but all distros suffer from screen ghosting, as demonstrated in this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqhkpU2K0dE).

My system uses an Intel Pentium J2900 with 4GB RAM, Intel on-board graphics and has an i915 chipset.

Also my i7 3770 with Intel graphics has same issue.

Seems like Intel HD graphics have problem. How can I resolve this issue?